# Getting OSX Connected Wi-Fi Network Name

Tags: objective-c, macos, wifi, ssid, system-configuration

I need to get the name of the currently connected Wi-Fi SSID on OSX.

I've messed with the SystemConfiguration framework, I feel like it is there (as I am able to get the name of the network locaiton) but I am not really finding a way of getting the Wi-Fi SSID.

Would appreciate any help. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the CoreWLAN framework: `CWInterface` has a property called `ssid`. The code below gets the current wireless interface and shows its BSD name and its SSID. It works on Mac OS 10.6+.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

int main() {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    CWInterface *wif = [CWInterface interface];

    NSLog(@"BSD if name: %@", wif.name);
    NSLog(@"SSID: %@", wif.ssid);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./wif
BSD if name: en1
SSID: Aetherius
```

Comment: Seems great. Will test as soon as I get home.

Comment: What if you have a ethernet connection then? I suppose the WLANInterface wont work for that (obviously), so what then? :)

Comment: In OS 10.10 `[CWInterface interface]` has been deprecated. Anyone have ideas for what to use instead?

Comment: @irosenb clang says you should use `-[CWWiFiClient interface]`, however I can't find any documentation for it and the class doesn't seem to exist in CoreWLAN framework. So I would just use `+[CWInterface interface]` anyway.

Answer (score 12):

For osX Yosemite 10.10 use

```
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

-(void)prettyFunctionName
{
  CWInterface* wifi = [[CWWiFiClient sharedWiFiClient] interface];

  NSLog(@"BSD if name: %@", wifi.interfaceName);
  NSLog(@"SSID: %@", wifi.ssid);
  NSLog(@"txRate: %f", wifi.transmitRate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've been looking for this :)