# Get APN (Access Point Name) name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

Does anyone have any clues on how to read the current APN (Access Point Name) name or apn address on iOS6?

I've looked into `CFNetwork` but doesn't seem like the right way to go.

Very hard to find any info on this because of the Apple Push Notifications ambiguation...

Any help would really be appreciated here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740932/getting-osx-connected-wi-fi-network-name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967511/ios-get-current-wlan-network-name

Comment: @KeithSmiley: I believe (and might be wrong) that OP is asking about mobile APN (GPRS/3G) and not about SSID.

Comment: @rokjarc yea I wasn't sure if that was the intention or not so just to be safe.

Comment: @goncaloGomes: i'm affraid that the closest you can get to this information (without using private libraries) is to obtain MNC,MCC and carrier name trough CTCarrier

Comment: hey guys, sorry was without internet for a while. This is indeed about mobile APN details. @rokjarc, the MNC and MCC combination won't help me in this case unfortunately, because I'm after checking that the (not even specified yet) european standard APN for Local Breakout is configured on the device... But this would help other people I'm sure so if you want put it as an answer and after I have exhausted other options I'll accept yours or I'll put it myself on the question updates.

Comment: BTW, @rokjarc sorry for the noob question but I wouldn't want to use private libraries because? is it that Apple wouldn't approve the app if it was using them probably...

Comment: Exactly that: any usage of private (undocumented) API-s means you won't be able to publish your app in the App Store. I wouldn't put this MNC/MCC as an answer yet - there might be a better answer to your question outthere somewhere :)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why do you need this?