# How do I get the current wifi network name after Yosemite in Swift?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, osx-yosemite

In Mavericks I was using `[CWInterface interface]` to grab the currently connected network. That has [been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreWLAN/Reference/CWInterface_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CWInterface/interface) for Yosemite.

As usual Apple documentation provides no guidance on this topic.

So how can I get the currently connected Wifi network name in Yosemite with Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out. If you pass `nil` to the `interfaceName`, it will give you the currently connected wifi network. You can then call `ssid()` to get the name of the network.

Like so: `CWInterface(interfaceName: nil).ssid()`

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode 10.2 • Swift 5 or later • OSX Mojave**

```
import CoreWLAN

var ssid: String {
    return CWWiFiClient.shared().interface(withName: nil)?.ssid() ?? ""
}
```