How to get the current Wi-Fi SSID in Swift on macOS?
I’m trying to write a basic Swift script to get the name of the Wi-Fi network I’m connected to on macOS. However, even when connected to Wi-Fi, it prints: Not connected to any Wi-Fi network.
import Foundation
import CoreWLAN

// Create a Wi-Fi client instance
if let wifiClient = CWWiFiClient.shared().interface(),
   let ssid = wifiClient.ssid() {
    print("Connected to Wi-Fi: \(ssid)")
} else {
    print("Not connected to any Wi-Fi network.")
}

Additionally, I tried using the following shell commands:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s

but returns a deprecation warning:
WARNING: The airport command line tool is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
For diagnosing Wi-Fi related issues, use the Wireless Diagnostics app or the wdutil command line tool.

and also with networksetup -getairportnetwork en0:
You are not associated with an AirPort network.

Is there a way to fix this issue or an alternative approach to retrieve the current Wi-Fi SSID without needing sudo access?
Specifications: macOS Sequoia 15.0 Apple Silicon M3 Pro
UPDATE: Today I reset my mac to the factory settings and the system installed Sonoma as the default OS. I have tried both the terminal command networksetup and the swift method and they work fine. After updating again to Sequoi the problem appears again so I think the problem is directly related to This new update. Unfortunately, I can't find any info about deprecation or warnings on both the man and the documentation of both methods.
NOTE FOR THE MODERATOR: You suggested How to get SSID of currently connected Wifi Network in Swift | iOS 14?, but as stated in my title, the problem pertains to macOS and NOT iOS. The code you provided is primarily applicable to iOS due to its usage of CoreLocation for location services. Additionally, my issue also involves shell commands, which suggests that it may be related to other factors beyond just programming.

Check this it may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517017/how-do-i-get-the-current-wifi-network-name-after-yosemite-in-swift

hi @channu, thanks for your help, unfortunately it doesn't print anything.. It's like I'm not connected to wifi

Have you enabled the location permission under sandbox and hardened runtime for your app?

hi @Paulw11, thanks for your comment, No I didn't since is just a script and not an app build with Xcode

Huh strange, using CWWiFiClient worked fine for me. E.g. running CWWiFiClient.shared().interface()!.ssid()! in the Swift repl returns my network name exactly. Could this be a sandboxing issue?

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171160/how-to-get-the-wi-fi-connection-status-from-terminal

If in a loop that one is resembling one of round-robin. Other should supply that list. Also for VPN.

As posted here: Apple Forum
and here: Ask Different
Sequoia broke something when you try to retrieve the SSID.
Currently, the only available solution is to use this:
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/Current Network/ {getline;$1=$1;print $0 | "tr -d ':'";exit}'

That integrated into Swift becomes this:
import Foundation

func getWiFiNetworkName() -> String {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/bash")
    process.arguments = ["-c", "system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/Current Network/ {getline;$1=$1;print $0 | \"tr -d \':\'\";exit}'"]

    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    do {
        try process.run()
    } catch {
        return "Error executing process."
    }

    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    return output ?? "No Wi-Fi network detected."
}

let networkName = getWiFiNetworkName()
print("Connected to: \(networkName)")

If I find a better solution, I will update this post with the new one.

So frustrating. Using sketchybar as an alternative to the default MacOS top bar and this seems like the only new solution.

It works, but the system_profiler SPAirPortDataType command is so slow!
you can get a little bit less verbose output, by using system_profiler SPAirPortDataType -detailLevel basic, but the command still takes a few seconds.
The full command would then be:
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType -detailLevel basic | awk '/Current Network/ {getline;$1=$1;print $0 | "tr -d ':'";exit}'

A faster version for Sequoia (which also determines the correct WiFi interface enX):
ipconfig getsummary "$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi|AirPort/{getline; print $NF}')" | grep '  SSID : ' | awk -F ': ' '{print $2}'

Takes 46 ms vs. 3.8 s on my system.

Thank you so much! Sequoia broke the SSID retrieval part of my Automator script to set Wi-Fi network configuration specifically required in my workplace. I just changed the script based on your suggestions and hope to see it works tomorrow.

This should be the accepted answer
