# Can I open ios wifi settings in a prompt dialog like UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

Programming with iOS, is it possible to open wifi settings on the device on a prompted dialog ? Like on a `UIAlertController` ?

Using the following code, I am able to directly land into the wifi settings of the device.

```
let url:NSURL! = NSURL(string : "prefs:root=WIFI")  
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

iOS gives a button at top left corner of screen to get back to my app in one click from the wifi settings page. But I am looking for ways to make this easier for my user. So, is it possible to launch ios wifi settings in a `modeless dialog` so that user has a feeling of staying within my app while interacting with ios wifi settings from my app ?

Looking for ways to simplify the user experience.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203307/how-to-display-a-list-of-wifi-networks-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: @FahadRehman . You misunderstood my question. I wish to programatically display the list wifi access points in my app manually at will. the question you mentioned tells how to let iOS prompt the the list of wifi access points if not on network.

Comment: So, my question still stands : Is it possible by some way display the wifi settings or list of wifi access points on a prompt dialog at will from my app ?